# Discrepancies between the rimes of a character and its lower character in Guangyun?

Tags: phonology, middle-chinese

and 䂕, for instance, are classified into 去聲十三祭韻 according to Guangyun, while their lower characters, 吠, are classified into 去聲二十廢韻. Is there any research that provides a list of (hopefully) all characters with this kind of discrepancy?